# JSoup and JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, android, jsoup

I am trying to post something on this website:

> www.omegastrike.co.uk

using an Android app I am making. I want to post it in the shoutbox part, wich is using javascript to do this. I tried using JSoup, but it doesn't support JavaScript. I also tried using HTMLUnit, but that doesn't support Android. Is there any other way of doing it?
This is the Javascript use for the posting:

```
postShout: function() {
        message = $("shout_data").value;
        if (message == "") {
            return false;
        }

        $("shouting-status").value = ShoutBox.lang[0];

        postData = "shout_data="+encodeURIComponent(message).replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
        new Ajax.Request('xmlhttp.php?action=add_shout', {method: 'post', postBody: postData, onComplete: function(request) { ShoutBox.postedShout(request); }});
    },
```

Can I do something with the Ajax request perhaps? or does anyone have any other ideas to get this done? I do not want to use WebView. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `POST` with Jsoup, no?

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/xmlhttp.php?action=add_shout")
.data("shout_data", "Your shout data in java")
.method(Method.POST)
.execute()
```

Comment: Correct, but this isn't just a normal post. The field and button don't have a name associated with them. I was told I needed to find another way

Comment: @BlackMagic I don't see exactly what you mean... If the actual posting is done by an ajax POST request, it shouldn't matter if you post it from Jsoup... Maybe there are some other client-server communications before that allow the server to determine whether the post should be accepted, but you can replicate all that with Jsoup I think...

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean now. Thanks, I think this might help me out!